# How to solve an overconstrained system of equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, physics, classical-mechanics

What is the easiest codeable way to solve an overconstrained static model?  How does Force Effect https://forceeffect.autodesk.com do it?  Given a 10m long bar angled as the hypotenuse of a 3, 4, 5 triangle with an xy pin constraint a (0,0), another xy constraint at (4,3), and a vertical force of 100N applied down at (10,6) Force Effect calculates the x and y reaction forces below at C and A. I am not as interested in this particular answer in how to get to it by a codeable algorithm.

[image]

So the equations are:

Sum Moments about C = 0 =>  Yca(Rax)  + Xca(Ray) +  Xcb(F1) = 0 =>  3 Rax - 4 Ray = -4(-100)

Sum Moments about A = 0 => Yac(Rcx) + Xac(Rcy) + Xab(F1) = 0 =>  - 3 Rcx + 4 Rcy = -8(-100)

Sum Forces Y = 0 => Ray + Rcy + F1 = 0 => Ray + Rcy = -(-100)

Sum Forces X = 0 => Rax + Rcx = 0

Which could translate to a 4x4 matrix:  Ax = b

```
|  3.   -4.    0.    0. |   | Rax |  =  | 400 |
|  0.    0.   -3.    4. |   | Ray |  =  | 800 |
|  0.    1.    0.    1. |   | Rcx |  =  | 100 |
|  1.    0.    1.    0. |   | Rcy |  =  |   0 |
```

And attempting to solve for x = inv(A)* b gives the following error in SciLab (or MatLab)
-->inv(A)
       !--error 19 
Problem is singular.

So the matrix is not invertible- whatever that means!

Turns out that Rcx = -Rax, so substituting that can make for a smaller 3x3 matrix.

3 Rax - 4 Ray = -4(-100)

3 Rax + 4 Rcy = -8(-100)

Ray + Rcy = -(-100)

3x3 matrix: Ax=b

```
|  3.   -4.    0.  |   | Rax |  =  | 400 |
|  3.    0.    4.  |   | Ray |  =  | 800 |
|  0.    1.    1.  |   | Rcy |  =  | 100 |
```

Attempting to solve for x = inv(A)* b still gives the following error in SciLab (or MatLab)
-->inv(A)
       !--error 19

I’d be open to some sort of regular algebra substitution method to solve it if that is any easier.
Please help.  This is not homework.

I’d be open to some sort of substitution method to solve it if that is any easier.
Please help.  This is not homework.  This is a simplified version of a real-world problem of a large free body being held in place by two fixed pins.  It is not dynamic – nothing is moving.

Comment: I do not use MatLab or SciLab. What I don't like is the space between the $-$ sign and the $3$ (second line in the matrix. Could you fix it and tell me if you still have the problem. I don't have any trouble on my side.

Comment: The issue is that one of your 4 equations is redundant; it's a consequence  of others. So, you don't have enough equations to determine the reaction forces. Try to think of a condition you haven't used yet.

Comment: [Cross-posted on Engineering](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2683/how-to-solve-an-overconstrained-static-free-body-diagram). Please post on one site at a time. You can delete this copy, for example.

Comment: I hear you.  There were no replies there.  I am starting to wonder if it is just a math problem.